# What does "[LspTrace]" mean?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt project, and I can only debug it once when I start my computer.

So if I want to continue debugging, I have to restart the computer.

I don't know why.

**Here are some errors:**

```
[LspTrace]ReadAccConfig returns false!

[LspTrace]FindMatchingProvider: inInfo is one of the LSPs entry.
[LspTrace]WSPStartup end: 0, protocol=6

Exception at 0x7ffff7664008, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance) in gsutilityd!tinyxml2::XMLNode::GetDocument
Debugging has finished
```

**What do they mean?**

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with Qt nor debugging. Your application changes the global state of your system, i.e. starts a logging agent, etc. The second time you start it, the state is not as expected, and your application fails.